# mysql consums more space on openshift than on old host

Tags: mysql, openshift

I have a file data.sql which is 418M big.

On openshift I created a scaleable app and added mysql.

I enabled port-forwarding and now I try to import the data via `mysql ... < data.sql` which works fine so far. BUT after a while `rhc show-app forum --gears quota` shows:

```
Gear                     Cartridges            Used Limit
------------------------ ------------------- ------ -----
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx haproxy-1.4 php-5.4 211 MB  1 GB
xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx mysql-5.5             1 GB  1 GB
```

and mysql stops working. I expected openshift to handle the 418M data file without any problems. So I checked my old host and there its bigger, too, but not over 1GB:

```
# du -hc /var/lib/mysql/data
761M    /var/lib/mysql/data/
```

what is happening here? Why does the db scale up over 1GB on openshift?

Answer (score 0):

How much space was taken up BEFORE you loaded the sql file onto the server?  Your mysql installation is also taking up space, along with indexes, etc.

Comment: before pulling the sql-data: about 20M